# Xamarin.iOS - random crash with navigation

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm strugglying with my Xamarin.iOS application.
Randomly my app will crash on the `ViewDidLoad` Method with an **Invalid cast exception**.

> '`Test.iOS.UI.Catalog.CatalogViewController`' (Objective-C type: '`WorkZoneSelectorViewController`') to type '`Test.iOS.UI.WorkZoneSelector.WorkZoneSelectorViewController`'

As you can see in one of my crash logs, the system mixed up the types of my controllers between C# and Objective-C.

How can that be possible?

Comment: What `Xamarin.iOS` version is the app compiled with?

Comment: Hello, I'm using the last version of xamarin.IOS. I have all the update done on my mac. So i supposed i'm using the 11.4 Xamarin.Ios

Comment: Do you have a reproducible test case for this (or a semi-reproducible case)? Would really need to see the UIViewController navigation flow.

Comment: I gonna try to upload you a test project if i can reproduce this behaviour without all my code.

Comment: Do you have an idea of a tool i could use to see what happen when i'm switching the viewController to try understand this problem?